# React FullCalendar not showing resources/rooms

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am testing React FullCalendar for a project and I am having difficulties with the resources/rooms. Basically they are not appearing and I get this warning in the console **Unknown option 'resources'**

I have tried using json and js object but none of them seems to work.

You can also view it in codesandox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dev-1800-fullcalendartest-jc214o?file=/src/App.js:0-978)

Any help is appreciated

```
export default function App() {
  const lunch = new Date();
  const events = [
    {
      title: "Lunch",
      start: lunch
    }
  ];

  const resources = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Room 1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "Display room"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "MR-Fujita"
    }
  ]
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FullCalendar
        events={events}
        resources={resources}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
          center: "title",
          right: "prevYear,prev,next,nextYear"
        }}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridWeek"
        height="100%"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think you included the right plugin - see the example at: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view

Comment: Yep, you are right, I was missing to import and include the pluging. Thank you for the help

Comment: @ADyson feel free to post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `resourceTimeGridPlugin` plugin in your project via the calendar options, e.g:

```
plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, resourceTimeGridPlugin ]}
```

See the example at: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view

Bear in mind that this is a premium feature so you'd need a valid license.